# Java Spring Boot Download file with filename containing special characters produces zero byte downloaded file

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
File System : Linux
Spring Boot : 2.1.4
Spring framework: 5.1.6.RELEASE
Library used : org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
```

The problem exists for example in German characters. For filename containing `space %20` (encoded) works fine.

The problematic file is named `Einzelhändler überprüfen.pdf` and it's 12KB

Locally in windows and IntelliJ it works okay but in Linux it doesn't download .

```
final String relativePath = Paths.get(directory, UriUtils.decode(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).toString();

 

final FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(relativePath);
final String actualFileName = res.getFile().toPath().getFileName().toString();

 

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("attachment").filename(actualFileName).build());

 

return new ResponseEntity<>(res, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

`final String actualFileName = res.getFile().toPath().getFileName().toString();`

I have tried also this line with

`final String actualFileName = UriUtils.encode(res.getFile().toPath().getFileName().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).toString()`

Does anybody know why this problem is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with different file encodings. The best approach would be that you first analyze which OS your application running at and then work your way up to result like this.

```
 String input = new String(input_bytes, StandartCharsets.UTF_8); // on linux
 String input = new String(input_bytes, StandartCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // on windows
```

And create a helper class as follows:

```
  class OsUtils
{
   private static String OS = null;
   public static String getOsName()
   {
      if(OS == null) { OS = System.getProperty("os.name"); }
      return OS;
   }
   public static boolean isWindows()
   {
      return getOsName().startsWith("Windows");
   }

   public static boolean isUnix() {
       return getOsName().contains("nux");
   };// and so on
}
```

After, with some simple if check using the OsUtils classs, you can check which one to use. Hope it works!